# C# Array memory allocation

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, camera

I am writing a WinForm application using Andor_SDK (sdk for the camera they provided). SDK is written in a few languages: c++, c#,vb, labview. 
My problem is the following:
In order to retreive the image(s) from the camera's internal memory I need to call a function.

c++:

```
unsigned int WINAPI GetOldestImage(at_32* arr, unsigned long size)
```

To use this function, you would allocate big enough array (in regards to image size and number of them) and pass that pointer to the function. In c++ that wouldn't be a problem

My question is how can i do something similar that works in c#

for reference, function called in c# is:

```
uint Andor_SDK.GetOldestImage(int[] arr, uint size)
```

Comment: By any chance are you looking for a flexible array, which can be extended in size on need basis. As the actual size may vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've shown the C# function signature, I'm assuming that means your or someone else has already written the P/Invoke definitions for this C API.

Given that, you should be able to call it like this:

```
int[] arr = new int[1024];
uint result = Andor_SDK.GetOldestImage(arr, arr.Length);
```

Comment: I think i have tried something like this, but i might have done it in the wrong scope, will check again asap

Comment: If i try to get size of array in that way, it keeps throwing an: "Array size is incorrect"

Comment: Well, it's time to dig in to that code then, to see where that exception is raised.

Comment: uint result from the function is a code that refers to "Array size is incorrect". Is just declaring and initializing empty array enough?

Comment: With a little typecasting and trying it out, this old classic worked! Thank you!